# What is the goal of this community?

Tags: discussion

When the Buddha attained liberation he immediately dedicated his life to the selfless goal of helping others end their suffering.

There are people posting questions who are in need of responses that can steer them in the right direction. All I have seen is dogmatic responses that they never accept as an answer. I am just asking you to think about what you are doing. Is that OK?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you saying that answers should be less "dogmatic"? Might you explain what that word means, perhaps with references to specific examples of some more-dogmatic ('worse') and less-dogmatic ('better') answers? Do you mean the word literally, i.e. a dogmatic answer being any answer which references dogma, canonical scripture, e.g. suttas?

Comment: What is the goal of this community? Freedom should not be sacrificed for safety, nor safety for freedom. It must be difficult sometimes trying to be a fair moderator.

Comment: What way is not one way or another?  I don't know what is going on but when someone tries to persuade you, you don't have to take it personally. Stuff is happening. That's it. Samsara isn't anything personal.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of this community is not to answer ones individual questions or personal issues, something the OP would and should need to go and deal with IRL, ideally with the sangha.
The goal of the community is to answer questions in a way that is used as a source of information, so that others can search for the answers to the questions they seek themselves.

i.e, OP states "X event happened to me, how do I deal with the suffering of X event"
People answer with quoting sources of Buddhas teachings, not personal anecdotes.

This is NOT a self help group. If you think it is and that is something you want you are in the wrong place. This is a reference of information relating to Buddhas teachings and Buddhism. Evident as to you or I can actually alter the question itself to make it more in line with the intentions of the group, to be less of a personal question and more generic to fit in line as a source of information.

The reason why answers are not "chosen" is simply because the OP didn't know the answer to the question, or the question would not have been asked in the first place. The answers are multiple faced and in most cases all correct. As well as the thread gets neglected by OP. There is only a need to actually close a thread when no more information can be added, which in most cases is never. We can still answer questions from a decade ago if you like. Something people often do in fact!.

Also choosing an answer is not needed as the voting system does the same job. Its akin to old yahoo answers format.

Comment: Who is the OP? Maybe some people don't know what that is. Not me of course.

Comment: If you do not know what basic online acronym, abbreviations and general decades old online slang are....well you should not be using the internet in such a way that you are trying to give opinions, but instead need to git gud at interwebz and lurk moar before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a community.

The community has long left and what remains is the archive, three moderators (Andrei,  Ruben, Chris) and a Nick...

I only use this site as an archive to occasionally answer my own questions which might be of interest to people studying the EBTs.